# How to set the screen brightness as DialogInterface does it

Tags: android, android-view

I would like to change the brightness of my screen, except a little part where I would like to show a listView.

This is made for the DialogInterface's by Android and I would like to know how to do this.
In the DialogInterface, the dialog has a normal brightness and all the other elements goes on the background with a smaller brightness.

Thank you.

Comment: Create a activity with listview and give Dialog theme to that activity.

Comment: Thank you @Hiral, how to give a DialogTheme to the second activity ehere I have my list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say,you have ShowDialogActivity where your listview resides.Then you can do this in your **manifest.xml:**

```
...
<application android:label="@string/app_name">
   ...
   <activity android:name=".ShowDialogActivity" android:theme="@style/Dialog"/>
</application>
...
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this immediately.

Comment: I have a little problem @Hiral, If I understood, I have to create a second activity where I have to implement my listView. On the main activity, I have set an image when onClick, this will create a new intent and start the activity for result. But on my ListActivity, I have to set a content view or? How to know what shuld be dimmed and what not?

Comment: you just have to create new activity with listview in its xml.Then when you call that activity,it will dim everything else under the activity(as dialogs do) and let you see the listview brighten. So basically you will have to shift your listview from your old activity to new one!

Comment: Thank you, but right now, when I call the new activity with an intent, i change the view and only the list is shown.

Comment: yes.. that would be the behavior only.won't that work for you? i mean,its not exact what you wanted but kind of similar.

Comment: It's better now, in the manifest, it should be: <activity 
            android:name=".JournalSelectingDialog"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
             ></activity>

Comment: It works now, but the style is not really adapted to what I need. I don't know if we can realy use only the dimming of this theme, not all the theme

Comment: AFAIK,you cannot make specific components to be dimmed when one is shown brighten.Using themes,you can dim out underneath activity and show current activity brighten.

Comment: Ok, but there is no other theme which gives only the dimming of the first activity, without all the Dialog parametres?

Comment: then you will have to customize dialog theme.

Comment: Ouh, ok, and how can i do this, where can i find it?

Comment: find SampleCustomDialog here:http://code.google.com/p/androgames-sample/source/browse/#svn%2FSampleCustomDialog%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Answer (score 5):

To set the background as dim for dialogue interface, following is the code snippet:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
/** set the dim amount of the settings activity */
lp.dimAmount = 0.5f;
dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Comment: Thank you @jyotiprakash, but how could i do this for a listview or a image for example?